# System.out.println("Hello"); = (No explicit return value)

Tags: java, eclipse, console, system.out

Tried printing Hello. But nothing was printed on console. 
It returned the value as (void).
Suggest a solution

Attached the expression as [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac73p.jpg).

```
@Service("DetailsDAO") 
public class DetailsDAOImpl implements DetailsDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DetailsDAOImpl.class);

    @Override 
    public List < DetailsVO > getDetails(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        logger.info("Hello");
        List < DetailsVO > detailList = new ArrayList < DetailsVO > ();
        DetailsVO detVo = new DetailsVO();
        detVo.setAdd1("abc");
        detVo.setAdd2("qwe");
        detailList.add(detVo);
        return detailList;
    }
}
```

Comment: thats because the println call returns void.

Comment: You are probably looking in the wrong place for your console output. It’s unlikely that it gets eaten somewhere.

Comment: So in eclipse, help me where can i find the console output. System.out.println("Hello") will be print on the console,right?

Comment: @Prakash Are you sure you `getDetails` is called somewhere else, maybe another instance is `@Autowired` and then called? Could you provide and code calling the method?

Comment: It is not called anywhere.

Comment: @Prakash If `getDetails` is not called anywhere, then why do you expect to see any output?

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is not very clear and i suggest you post some code.

A simple *Hello World* program looks like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Please note that `System.out.println` does not return anything, it simply does what its name means: Print a line on the console.

Comment: It neither answers the question nor provides anything that is likely to be different from the asker’s own code in any significant way.

Comment: @OleV.V Then the question is probably not well-asked. Im voting to close this question now.

Comment: @Service("DetailsDAO")
public class DetailsDAOImpl implements DetailsDAO{
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DetailsDAOImpl.class);
@Override
 public List<DetailsVO> getDetails(String name) {
  System.out.println("Hello");
  logger.info("Hello");
  List<DetailsVO> detailList=new ArrayList<DetailsVO>();
  DetailsVO detVo = new DetailsVO();
  detVo.setAdd1("abc");
  detVo.setAdd2("qwe");
  detailList.add(detVo);
  return detailList;
 }
This is my code
I tried logging with log4j also. No output in the console for both Sytem.out.println() and logger.info.